# A formal condition for a functor to preserve compact objects

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $L\dashv R : {\cal C}\leftrightarrows\cal D$ be an adjunction in $\bf Cat$. It is well-known that if $R$ is $\alpha$-accessible then $L$ preserves $\alpha$-presentable objects: if $J$ is an $\alpha$-filtered category, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\textstyle {\cal D}(Lc,\varinjlim_J d_j) &\textstyle \cong {\cal C}(c, R(\varinjlim_J d_j))\\
& \textstyle \cong {\cal C}(c, \varinjlim_J Rd_j )\\
& \textstyle \cong \varinjlim_J {\cal C}(c, Rd_j )\\
& \textstyle \cong \varinjlim_J {\cal C}(Lc, d_j )
\end{align*}
$$
Now, I would like to know if the following abstraction of what happens makes sense, and if yes, how to prove it properly.

1. **Definition.** A functor $F : A\to B$ is an *$\sf Ind$-cell* if it preserves all Yoneda extensions $\text{Lan}_y\lambda$ of functors $\lambda : G\to A$:
   [image]
2. **Claim.** if $L\dashv F$ is an adjunction, and $F : {\sf Ind}(G)\to {\sf Ind}(G')$ is an $\sf Ind$-cell, then the left lifting $\text{Lift}_y(Ly')$ exists in the diagram
   [image]

Comment: By a "lift", do you mean the dual notion to a Kan extension, or do you simply mean a functor which makes the diagram commute up to isomorphism? If the latter, then I agree that the conclusion of the claim is a re-phrasing of "L preserves compact objects" _if $G$ is idempotent-complete_, and thus in this case the Claim is true, and equivalent to the statement "the left adjoint of a (finitely) accessible functor preserves compact objects". I don't know if there is, say, a 2-categorical proof, though. The necessity of the hypothesis of idempotent-completeness bothers me a bit...

Comment: I believe there is a characterization of homomorphisms of algebras for any lax-idempotent 2-monad which has something to do with preserving certain extension cells, which might be interesting to you.

Comment: I mean the former concept, if possible. Expand your second comment, I'm certainly interested!

Comment: I tracked down what I seemed to recall -- I learned about this in Definition 4 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.086930), attributed to Marmolejo and Wood. The idea is that any lax-idempotent 2-monad can be thought of as a free cocompletion 2-monad, so you can characterize algebras by existence of certain extensions, and morphisms by preservation thereof. This really doesn't get to the question of thinking about adjoints to algebra morphisms, it's just something your (1) reminded me of.

Comment: Aha! That's even a definition I'm using. I'll think about it for a while.